# Threaded access log replayer for Tomcat?

Tags: automated-tests, tomcat6

Suffered a "DOS" attack, which brought down my Tomcat 6 server by issuing numerous GET requests. I would like to replay the access file, preferably with multiple threads. Anyone know a good tool, or do I need to write it myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter can do it, found [this guide](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_accesslog_sampler_step_by_step.pdf).